# angular login page password filed show double eye icon

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, frontend

I am new to Angular and I want to create a login page with a password input field that includes a 'fa fa-eye' icon to show and hide the password. However, I'm noticing that two eye icons are being displayed when I enter my password in the field.

here is my html code

```html
<div class="class form-group pt-3">
  <div class="input-field">
    <span class="fa fa-lock p-2"></span>
    <input formControlName="password" [type]="type" placeholder="Password" />
    <span (click)="hideShowPass()" class="fa {{eyeIcon}}"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<small
  *ngIf="loginForm.controls['password'].dirty && loginForm.hasError('required', 'password')"
  class="text-danger"
>
  *Password is required
</small>
```

here is my type script class

```typescript
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  type: string = 'password';
  isText: boolean = false;
  eyeIcon:  string = 'fa-eye-slash'
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]

    })
  }

  hideShowPass(){
    this.isText = !this.isText
    this.isText ? this.eyeIcon = "fa-eye" : this.eyeIcon = "fa-eye-slash";
    this.isText ? this.type = "text" : this.type = "password"
  }
}
```

and her is my css class

```css
input[type='text'],
input[type='password']{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.fa-eye-slash.btn{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

thanks for advance

i want only show a single eye icon on the input field

Comment: `this.eyeIcon =  this.isText ? "fa-eye" : "fa-eye-slash";`
  `this.type = this.isText ?  "text" : "password";` try this

Comment: @RaviAshara it's not workin

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of ternary operator is bit odd, as mentioned in the comment. This way it is better and easier to read

```typescript
hideShowPass(){
  this.isText = !this.isText
  this.type = this.isText ? "text" : "password";
}
```

I would also recommend to use `[ngClass]`, that way you don't need to bother with variable for the class. Assign correct CSS class in HTML, using `isText` to determine the correct class

```html
<span 
  (click)="hideShowPass()"
  class="fa" 
  [ngClass]="{'fa-eye': isText, 'fa-eye-slash': !isText }">
</span>
```